# Use of variable within the call of a function

Tags: macros, conditionals, syntax, variable

I need to call various commands based on some combination of conditions. Due to a huge number of possible cases, it would be very convenient to use variables inside the name of the called command. Is it possible?

### Here is a simplified example:

Let's say I have defined a group of commands with composed names, such as:

```
\newcommand{\mycommandUpLeft}[1]{...something using #1...}
\newcommand{\mycommandUpRight}[1]{...something else using #1...}
\newcommand{\mycommandDownLeft}[1]{...something else using #1...}
\newcommand{\mycommandDownRight}[1]{...something else using #1...}
```

I would like to call them from another meta command such as:

```
\newcommand{\metacommand}[3]{%
   \mycommand#1#2{#3}   % wished behavior, but not possible using this syntax
}%
```

where argument 1 and 2 are vertical and horizontal direction, respectively.
This would be used like this :

```
\metacommand{Down}{Left}{some content}
```

expecting it to act as

```
\mycommandDownLeft{some content}
```

### Note :

Using `\ifthenelse` from `ifthen` package could be a workaround, but is not ideal since it would require a very long and redundant tree structure.

Thanks!

Comment: Quite easy with `etoolbox`, much more powerful than `ifthen`, also include easy access to the method Steven describes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycommandUpRight}[1]{Up Right of #1...}
\newcommand{\mycommandDownLeft}[1]{Down Left of #1...}
\newcommand\metacommand[3]{\csname mycommand#1#2\endcsname{#3}}
\begin{document}
\mycommandDownLeft{some content}

\metacommand{Down}{Left}{other content}

\metacommand{Up}{Right}{third content}
\end{document}
```

[image]